# How do I select the first of a number of rows sharing a single field in common using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table of users, some of which share an email address. I want to select the first record for a given email address, based on a rank column that is assigned depending on their occupation. For example:

```
name              occupation           email                  rank
====================================================================
test user         accountant           sample@sample.com      5
test user         sales rep            sample@sample.com      4
test user         ceo                  sample@sample.com      1
test user2        janitor              sample@sample2.com     10
test user2        secretary            sample@sample2.com     6
test user2        principal            sample@sample2.com     3
```

How can I select only the records with the highest rank per email address using SQL Server 2005? In other words, how can I transform the table above to this:

```
name              occupation           email                  rank
====================================================================
test user         ceo                  sample@sample.com      1
test user2        principal            sample@sample2.com     3
```

Rank is not guaranteed to be unique. In the case where two people share the top rank, either row is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from my_table
join (select email, min(rank) as rank from my_table group by email) min_ranks
on min_ranks.email = my_table.email and min_ranks.rank = my_table.rank
```

Comment: What if 2+ rows match the value of min(rank)?

Comment: If two rows have the same rank, how would you choose between them? Your question said "the first record". Without an ID or some other indication of order, what does "first" mean?

Comment: It means I only want one of them. Which one doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This breaks a tie with `[rank]` but will not break a tie on `[rank],occupation`. If that tie is possible, just add more columns to the `ORDER BY`.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT name,occupation,email,[rank],
      rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY [rank],occupation) 
      FROM @x
)
SELECT name,occupation,email,[rank]
 FROM x
 WHERE rn = 1;
```